# Visual Studio Code Julia extension no longer allows multiple "Run File in New Process"

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am running julia v1.9.0 and Visual Studio Code 1.78.2.

I have several julia programs that I normally run concurrently using the "Julia: Run File in New Process" option from the drop down menu at the upper right side of vscode.  Just today, it no longer works -- vscode only allows one process to be active at a time.  The first task launches correctly, but all subsequent attempts to run other files gives the error "The task 'Julia: Run program1.jl (myworkspace)' is already active."

I am only able to run task at a time.  The problem started today.  I suspect it has something to do with a new vscode update.

Please help me to find a solution to this problem so that I can once again run multiple programs/tasks in vscode.

I tried using the menu run command and ctrl-F5 and got the same result.

the only workaround I've found is to:

1. open up multiple terminals
2. launch julia in each terminal
3. launch each program in separate julia/terminal instances using the include("program.jl") command.

Comment: Just to be sure, has your Julia extension for VS Code gotten updated? The previous version  v1.38.2 wasn't fully compatible with Julia 1.9, and the updated v1.47.2 version was released only a couple of days ago.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem. I guess if it worked and now it tells you off for trying opening multiple, it would imply it's a choice made by the developers. Maybe try asking in the [Github Issues of the extension](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues), and see if it's something they did or it's to do with VSCode itself?